# Clipper polygon offsetting and straight line vertices

Tags: geometry, line, polygon, vertices, clipperlib

I am trying to offset a polygon using clipper, and I need all the vertices from the original polygon to be mirrored in the offset polygon. The trouble is that when you pass a polygon with vertices on a straight line, you get back a polygon without any vertices on straight lines, as I have attempted to illustrate in this diagram:

Polygon Offsetting vertices
[image]

Does anybody know of a way to modify the behaviour of clipper, or a different library that can do this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Internal routine `FixupOutPolygon()` removes such (usually redundant) vertices (in version 4.8). I see no option to disable it.

Read the [license](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt). If it permits to modify sources for yourself, then you could comment out it's call in the sources.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. I ended up fixing my problem by just adding a small variation to the position of points added to straight lines.